# Date validation on server side in php codegnighter

Tags: php

I am trying date validation, for start date and end date,
My start date must be the current date and future date, it should not be past date.
My end date only future date its must not be the current date and start date.

here is my code which I tried

```
$startdate = $this->input->post('startdate');
        //echo $startdate;exit;
        $enddate = $this->input->post('enddate');
        $tempDt = explode('-',$startdate);
        $enddt =explode('-',$enddate);
        $newstartDt = $tempDt[2]."-". $tempDt[0]."-". $tempDt[1];
        $newendDt = $enddt[2]."-". $enddt[0]."-". $enddt[1];
        //echo $newendDt;exit;
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

        $date = date('Y-m-d');

        //echo $newstartDt."<br/>".$date."<br/>";

        //echo $date >= $newstartDt;exit;
        //echo $date;exit;      
          if ($newstartDt < $date)
          { 
              echo "Project Startdate must be future date or current date ";
              exit;
                $Message = array('msg'  => $msg);
                $this->session->set_userdata($Message);
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    location.href = "<?php echo site_url('admin/Project_controller/projectdetail'); ?>";
                </script>
                <?php
          }
          if (($newendDt < $date) && ($newendDt < $newstartDt))
          {
             // echo $newendDt;exit;
             //echo $newstartDt;exit;

                $msg = "end date should be grater than current date and  must be future date ";
                    $Message = array('msg'  => $msg);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($Message);
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        location.href = "<?php echo site_url('admin/Project_controller/projectdetail'); ?>";
                    </script>
                    <?php
          }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am trying to compare  date validation but  for current date validation is not working its working for start date but for end date must be futurre date its should not be cuurentdate for end date validation is not working..?